# Firebase connection error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

We are using Firebase, along with React, and usually it works fine. But at random times, the Firebase database will be unreachable. We use firebase for authentication as well, so during these times users are unable to log in.

The error is

```
A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred.
```

Here the the code for signing in

```
signIn() {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.setCustomParameters({
         'prompt': 'select_account'
    });
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
        var token = result.credential.accessToken;
        // The signed-in user info.
        var user = result.user;
    }.bind(this)).catch(function(error) {

        // Handle Errors here.
        var errorCode = error.code;
        var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(errorMessage);
        // The email of the user's account used.
        var email = error.email;
        // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
        var credential = error.credential;
        // ...
    });
}
```

Does anyone know what might be causing this?

Comment: Can you check your browser network console for when this happens and include a log of that?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be related to firebase's signInWithPopup function.Probably your browser try to open new tab instead of pop up when the function invoked.You must allow your browser to open pop up.Also when this problem occurs, reset your browser's cache and allow 3's party cookies and then try again.Finally if these are not working, the problem stem from your browser's bug.